# declaring i2c_msg yields gcc error: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: arrays, struct, gnu-make, i2c

I am generating a couple of wrapper files for i2c communication. these are written in C.

The header file looks like:

```
#ifndef IMX6QI2C_WRAPPER_H_
#define IMX6QI2C_WRAPPER_H_

#include <linux/i2c-dev.h> //contains definitions for:
                                   struct i2c_msg
                                   struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data

//fn declarations

#endif /* IMX6QI2C_WRAPPER_H_ */
```

the source file contains:

```
#include "imx6qi2c_wrapper.h"
#include <stdio.h>    //printf()
#include <unistd.h>    //for close()
#include <string.h>    //for MANY implicit decl. & -Wformat errs
#include <sys/types.h> //open()
#include <sys/stat.h>  //open()
#include <fcntl.h>     //open(),O_RDWR
#include <sys/ioctl.h> //ioctl()
#include <errno.h>     //errno,strerror()

#define I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR    1
#define I2CMSGS_TOTAL_RD    2
#define I2C_M_WR                0x00 //missing from i2c_msg flags


int imxSend_i2cMsg(const int i2c_fd, 
                   struct i2c_msg *i2cMsgArray, 
                   const unsigned int arraySize){ 

     //do stuff
}


int imxSend_i2cByte(const int i2c_fd,
                    const unsigned char i2cAddress,
                    const unsigned char devRegister,
                    const unsigned char value){

    struct i2c_msg i2cmsg[2];

    //do stuff

    ret=imxSend_i2cMsg(i2c_fd,&i2cmsg,I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR);

    //do more stuff
}
```

now, compiler is fine with the definition of "imxSend_i2cMsg()", as far as `struct i2c_msg *i2cMsgArray` is concerned.

But it has a problem with the declaration of the local variable `struct i2c_msg i2cmsg[2]`, in function "imxSend_i2cByte()".

The error is : "array type has incomplete element type".

And I am left wondering.

Could it possibly be related to #include directives?
In my example, `i2c-dev.h` that contains the definitions of "struct i2c_msg", is #included in `i2c_wrapper.h` and the latter is then included in the `i2c_wrapper.c` file. To my understanding, this means that the source file CAN indeed "see" the "struct i2c_msg". No?

I have seen this question on numerous occasions in stackoverflow but the answer is still not obvious. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us a minimal complete example, including the definition of `i2c_msg`?

Answer (score 0):

ok it was a erroneous "-I" flag in my makefile.
I was not pointing correctly to the location of the "linux/i2c-dev.h"